# Git Windows: Cannot clone/checkout repository paths with spaces

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows

I am trying to checkout a repository with paths that have spaces.
git clone/checkout failed. The following error is returned

```
fatal: cannot create directory at 'main-path/some-folder-with-space /another-folder': No such file or directory
```

**Resolved by:**

1. Download project zip from github.
2. Extract the project.
3. git init
4. git remote add origin git@github.com:MainRepo/project.git
5. git fetch --all

Project is now successfully cloned to my windows machine. I can checkout the remote branches without any errors.

Comment: checkout [this] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19180612/fatal-cannot-create-directory-at-root-wp-content-cache-page-enhanced-no-s) may help you

Comment: It seems Windows and NTFS doesn't handle spaces at the start or the end of a file or folder name rather well so I would try to avoid this. My attempts to reproduce a problem seems to indicate that Windows itself will silently strip away these spaces when creating the folder, and will silently ignore the spaces when attempting to access the folder **from .NET**, but not from other tools not based on .NET.

Answer (score 1):

Put the address in quotes

```
git clone "some/folder/with spaces/here.git"
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're on the command line, you can just escape spaces with `\`.

I tried with `git clone ../some\ folder\ with\ spaces/`.

EDIT: The target folder also contains spaces. No Problem. Can you elaborate on *how* you tried to clone? Are you using command line or some gui?

Comment: I am simply cloning a whole project but it is failing because some of the folders inside contain spaces git@github.com:comp/project.git

Comment: It doesn't look like it **contains** spaces, it looks like it **ends with** a space.

Answer (score 0):

This was resolved by using a lower version of Git Bash (1.9.5) I was using version 2.5.1 when I encountered this issue.